# Angular 6 Firebase Custom Auth with token

Tags: angular, firebase, angular6, angularfire2, angularfire5

I am trying to do authentication to firebase server to get the details I used this when I was using angular 1.6

```
var fbRef = new Firebase(decodedUtSession.fburl);
fbRef.authWithCustomToken(decodedUtSession.fbtkn, function(error, authData) {
$rootScope.fbRef = fbRef;
if(error){
    console.log("Firebase Login Failed!", error);
  }
});
```

But Now I am upgrading my app to angular 6 with @angular/fire for firebase I tried the below code for custom auth but I am always getting invalidAuthTokeb though token is valid and working fine with the angular 1.6 app.

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { FirebaseAuth } from '@angular/fire';

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

 this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCustomToken(devToken).then((data) => {
     console.log(data);
 });
```

Can anyone please help me how to do authentication in a proper way TIA.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the token correctly? can you please show the error as well?

Comment: @JavierAviles i am getting this error and yes auth token is correct one

POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken?key=xxxx 400
zone.js:192 Uncaught 

L {code: "auth/invalid-custom-token", message: "AUDIENCE_MISMATCH"}
code: "auth/invalid-custom-token"
message: "AUDIENCE_MISMATCH"
__proto__: Error

Comment: Can you go to https://jwt.io and decode your custom token? let's see whats inside... also make sure your front client has the same project_id as the backend project

Comment: @JavierAviles I am generating token in backend and then via api call i am getting that token and after passing token to signInWithCustomToken() I am getting that error. is there any other way to do custom auth  in firebase with  angular 6.

Comment: If you want to do custom token auth, seems like the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 2+ uses Firebase SDK3.0, so backend should also be upgraded to have authentication.